# Accessing controller properties within controller function in ember

Tags: ember.js

I'm unable to access the controller property within a controller function:

```
App.ViewRController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    datas:null,
    actions:{

    viewfile:function() {
        let filename = this.get('filename');
        let count=0;
        let data;
        let self = this;

        if (filename != null)
        {
            filename = filename.trim();

            if(filename.length > 0)
            {
                try {
                    let obj= new XMLHttpRequest();
                    obj.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if(obj.readyState==4 && obj.status ==200)
                        {
                            let json = obj.responseText;
                            console.log(self);
                            data = JSON.parse(json);
                            self.set(datas, data);
                        }
                    }

                    let params = "filename=" + filename;
                    obj.open("POST","view");
                    obj.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    obj.send(params);
                    //this.set('datas',data);
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                     alert(e);
                }
            }
            else
                alert("enter filename");
        }
        else
            alert("enter filename");
    }
}
```

The template should iterate over the data object with properties. But I couldn't set the data property within the function in the controller.

Comment: That looks like a very outdated version of Ember... I would recommend updating your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to set a property with

```
self.set(datas,data);
```

But you need to be setting the "datas" property as a string:

```
self.set("datas", data);
```